# Where in Ubuntu SPI pins are configured?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I'm running Ubuntu on a custom embedded system. The SPI bus master is spi-pxa2xx. I've tried my code on several other systems and it worked fine. But on this system all I see is CS activity while I'm trying to send data over SPI. CLK, MISO and MOSI are staying low. I wanted to make sure that the bus master actually is configured correctly and is using the right pins for the SPI. My question is: Where in the kernel is the  pins/GPIOs configurations for every bus, and specifically for SPI. 
Thanks